# Batch set /a not working

Tags: batch-file

I've looked alot and can't find why this is happening. It's very simple but doesn't work.

```
:numbers
cls
set /p first=First:
set /p second=Second:
set /p third=Third:
set /p fourth=Fourth:
set /p fifth=Fifth:
goto solve
:solve
cls
set /a s-f= %second% - %first%
set /a t-s= %third% - %second%
```

But the last two lines don't work and I know it's these because I have tried an echo %variable_name% and it shows up as what I want but the /a doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s-f` isnot a valid variable name. If you use `s_f` instead, *that* variable will be set appropriately.

Comment: Well, it is a valid environment variable name in a general sense, but that name cannot be used in a SET /A statement. SET /A requires that names not contain math operators or delimiters.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that and will keep that in mind